# RBS Installation on webFrontEnd Failed

Tags: error, installation, rbs

During my installation of RBS on the Web Front End Server I have faced this error in the log file that end the installation

> *SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'C:\RBS\RBS.msi' against software restriction policy
>
>   SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\RBS\RBS.msi has a digital signature
>
>   SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\RBS\RBS.msi is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.*

Any idea?

Comment: Is this the First WFE?

Comment: do you have any group policies made by a system administrator that restrict installation of software?

Comment: i am accessing the server as spfarm account, so i dont think this user has any restrictions

Comment: User could be administrator on the sp farm and on the local machine, there could still be restrictions on installing software. Its worth checking with your Server administrator/support team.